# avast VS my Programm

Tags: c#, winforms

I have problem with my program. I make a simple mail-messenger, and in this code :

```
        var mail = new MailMessage();
        var smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru");
        smtpServer.Port = 25;
        smtpServer.Credentials = new 
        NetworkCredential("@mail.ru", "pass");
        smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;               
        mail.Body = text;
        mail.From = new MailAddress("@mail.ru");
        mail.To.Add("@mail.ru");
        smtpServer.Send(mail);           // in this moment
```

Avast find  the `idp generic` in moment of mail send. The other antiviruses (eset32, Kaspersky,cureit) do not see problems and danger in code. I also was try to send mail with mailkit.dll. how can I fix it?

Comment: False positives should be reported to Avast, not us.

Comment: And I bet the antivirus is upset by what it finds in your text not by how you write this code.

Comment: Avast is notoriously troublesome on a programmer's machine, it does not deal gracefully with an executable file suddenly appearing from no-where.

Comment: While this is not the same antivirus, it may help you solve the issue: https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/208968/VB-Net-SmtpServer-Send-mail-Winform-not-sending-em#answer2

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is probably using the standard SMTP client-to-server email submission port: 587.

```
smtpServer.Port = 587;
```

If you, for whatever reason, can't use the standard email submission port, use the Avast GUI to make exceptions. Doing it through the antivirus directly should allow your program to run on your machine, and that's all you want, *right*? ;)

You can try:

- Excluding your build directory from live scans
- Authorizing your process to use port 25
- [Avast help pages](https://www.avast.com/faq.php?article=AVKB25#artTitle) for further reading